# Sphinx search installation on linux server with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, linux, sphinx

I want to install and setup sphnix 2.2.3 search on my linux server with mysql, but  after installation complete, unfortunately the **"indexer"** command not running and giving me an error that /data/test1.spl file not found (AS I configure that path in sphinx.conf file)

Please suggest any idea to continue this.

Comment: Please post your sphinx.conf and the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: is the path writable ?

Comment: Yes the path is writable permission is 0777